# Centre div over four divs within container on responsive site

Tags: html, css, position

This is the image I have:

[image]

How do I centre the black circle, I have tried a number of ways, best has been using absolute, but i cannot make it responsive.

Its on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrAddy/jq50ptsd/)

And here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="leftTop"></div>
    <div class="rightTop"></div>
    <div class="leftBottom"></div>
    <div class="rightBottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.rightTop {
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    min-width:50%;
    height:250px;
}

.leftTop {
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    min-width:50%;
    max-width:50%;
    height:250px;
}

.rightBottom {
    float:right;
    background-color:yellow;
    min-width:50%;
    height:250px;
}

.leftBottom {
    float:left;
    background-color:orange;
    min-width:50%;
    max-width:50%;
    height:250px;
}

.center {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:black;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

As I have said above, I have managed to centre it using `LEFT, TOP` but it is not responsive.  Also it's not `50%` as I would expect.

Any ideas what it is i am doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Should the circle be horizontally and vertically be centered? The width of the circle, should be a fix width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `positioning` for this (getting rid of those inefficient and horrible `float` elements), in combination with the `calc` css3 property.

You may also be interested in using `vw` units, in which I have used to make the circle responsive to the width of the screen:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 5vw;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 90vw;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
.wrap .red {
  background: tomato;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wrap .yellow {
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
.wrap .green {
  background: lime;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.wrap .blue {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.wrap .black {
  background: black;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 10vw);
  top: calc(50% - 10vw);
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 10vw);
  left: calc(50% - 10vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @jbutler483 I will add though that the four divs around the circle are not hight responsive, so I shall have a play :)

Comment: @AndrewWalker: I have them set to vw (view width units) and so are responsive to width.

Comment: But the height does not change as the screen gets smaller.  I thought responsiveness meant the boxes would decrease in height and width ?

Comment: @AndrewWalker: To keep the circle 'circular' - which value do you want it to take? It currently is changing according to width - If it needs to be height, you can change the circles values to vh (view height measurements). Unless you just want to 'stretch' the circle, meaning it would be an oval instead? Otherwise, you would have to choose which to be responsive with (height or width) - developers usually mean 'responsive' as in 'screen width adjusts' - not so much the height of screen

Comment: Sorry, the circle is perfect and does exactly what I wanted it to, but as a consequence, when on a mobile device, although the circle behaves as it should, the divs around it, Tomato, Yellow, Blue, Green, shrink in width, but not as a ratio with height.  Perhaps it would be easier on smaller screens to remove the circle design and have instead a different layout?

Comment: @AndrewWalker: My snippet should do that? (since the .wrap height is set in vh units?)

Comment: Snippet does not do that on my chrome browser. It pulls the hight longer, while the width is shorter, and the circle gets smaller.  Have saying that, on a small screen it would not look that good anyway,  as the boxes would have text in them.  Hard to read ?

Answer (score 2):

just add `margin-left:-200px;` in

```
.center {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:black;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
}
```

here is the updated **[fiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/jq50ptsd/1/)**

Comment: that does centre it, and I changed the `top: 50%` to `top:50px`  which does centre, but its not responsive, the circle remains the same size?

Comment: you have provided the width 400px to the center div, the responsive will work up to 400px only.

Comment: you need to adjust the width and margin-left with media query accordingly

Comment: This isn't centered vertically in latest chrome (possibly due to the floated elements.)

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/jq50ptsd/3/)**

Added:

1. `top: 50%;`, and `left: 50%;` to make it displayed relative to its parent: `.main { position: relative`
2. Added `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to center it. To center it on its own center point :D

Answer (score 1):

You should be clearing the floats in your main container.

To do so add this to the main element:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="center"></div>
        <div class="leftTop"></div>
        <div class="rightTop"></div>
        <div class="leftBottom"></div>
        <div class="rightBottom"></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <style>
    /* Add this to your CSS */
    .clearfix{
       clear:both;
    }
    </style>
```

This will make the main container expand to the height of those floaters. After that you can use:

```
.center{
    margin-top:-200px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:black;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
}

**OR** 

.center { 
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:black;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%); /* This property doens't rely on pixels of the element, so the element can also be defined in percentages */
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in your code:

```
.center {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
}
```

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/gnhwork9/1/

Comment: this does not produce a responsive circle as OP has requested.